HPA cannot read metric value
I am implementing the Horizontal Pod Autoscalar for a asp.net core application, and added the required code snippet in the Program.cs, which is working for another project. I could see the data using the metrics endpoint while running the application in my local. However,when i deployed the code, am not able to see the http request calls to the metrics end point which is available in the logs of the application where hpa is working. How to troubleshoot that if the managed service of GCP is able to scrape the metrics.

I am getting below error:
unable to get metric
prometheus.googleapis.com/ap_custom_ratio/gauge: unable to fetch metrics from custon metrics API: googleap: Error 400
The supplied filter does not specify a valid combination of metric and monitored resource descriptors. The query will not return any time series., badRequest

Please be aware that because HPA views metrics as pseudo-resources, which means they are not case-sensitive, uppercase characters in the metric names are not accepted. So I would like you to examine this. Also please refer to this similar case.

Did you have time to check my comment? It helped you to solve your issue? If not,I am happy to assist further.What should I do when someone answers my question?

The error occurs mainly due to metrics-server crushing or unresponsiveness, try below steps to resolve your issue:
1.Verify whether metrics servers are reporting an OOM (Out of Memory) event. To check this, open the "Workload" tab on the GKE Console page, perform a search using "metrics-server," and then click the deployment name to view the deployment details. Select the name of the pod by clicking.Restarts that count higher than 0 already indicate that the container has failed or been terminated.
If yes, the modification in metrics-server-config configmap is permanent. Increase memoryPerNode in metrics-server-config  until there are no OOM events, follow this document.
2.Additionally  you can add the following  command in your metrics-server deployment file:
containers:
   - command:
     - /metrics-server
     - --metric-resolution=30s
     - --kubelet-insecure-tls
     - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
     name: metrics-server

I believe the metrics-server couldn't find the kubelet with InternalIP, hence the issue.For more information, follow the step by step instructions to set up HPA. Refer to this How to Enable KubeAPI server for HPA Auto Scaling Metrics.
